# c++ run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'n' was corrupted

Tags: visual-c++

I'm currently practicing array but I got the specified error every time I run the project, hope you could help me.

Here's my code;

```
int n[10];
int num, ans, i;

cout << "num\n";
cin >> num;
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    n[i] = num % 2;
}

cout << n[1];
return 0;
```

Comment: Please provide some more information from the error dumb in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the stack around `n` is indeed corrupted, as you're iterating once beyond the array's bounds (0 - 10). The valid indices are 0-9, hence your code should look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    n[i] = num % 2;
}
```